# the Hill estimator in R

Tags: r, time-series, tail, estimation

I am trying to find a package that has a working version of the Hill estimator for extreme value theory in R. Does anyone know what package exists to do this? A couple of searches produced several packages but their level of development (ie are they still full of bugs) is unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A note about searching methods: I find the sos package's `findFn` features very handy. Try this:

```
install.packages("sos")
load("sos")
findFn("Hill extreme")
```

Looking at the first couple of packages DESCRIPTION files from their Index pages:

```
Package: fExtremes
Version: 2160.78
Revision: 5405
Date: 2012-11-30
Title: Rmetrics - Extreme Financial Market Data
Author: Diethelm Wuertz and many others, see the SOURCE file

Package: evir
Version: 1.7-3
Date: 2011-07-22
Title: Extreme Values in R
Authors@R: c(person("Bernhard", "Pfaff", email = "bernhard@pfaffikus.de", role = c("aut", "cre")),
           person("Alexander", "McNeil", email = "mcneil@math.ethz.ch", role = "aut", comment = "S
           original (EVIS)"), person("Alec", "Stephenson", email = "alec_stephenson@hotmail.com",
           role = "trl", comment = "R port of EVIS"))
```

Those are credible names in the author lists. Are you having difficulties with either of those packages?

Comment: thanks! i did see those two but i couldn't tell if they were stable. it sounds like you are familiar with some of the authors so i'll take that as a yes. haven't actually tested them because that would involve me coding it up myself and then i wouldn't need the package.

Comment: The only author in that group of 4 that I do not recognize as an authority is Stevenson, and I think I have added him to my list of credible names by virtue of association. McNeil is part of the group at ETH that has been publishing for years. I recognize Wuertz and Pfaff for their many contributions to the R-world over the years. Rmetrics is a standard.